# How to use NSArray of NSArray object in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I declared a `NSArray` object in .h file as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSArray  *scnArray;
```

and in .h file under `- (void)viewDidLoad` I created three different `NSArray` objects as

```
NSArray  *obj1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"0",@"0",nil];
NSArray  *obj2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"3",@"0",nil];
NSArray  *obj3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"5",nil];

scnArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:obj1];
[scnArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:obj2];
[scnArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:obj3];
```

and if I access this scnArray from any other function

`NSArray *caseArray = [scnArray objectAtIndex:index];`//index will be 0, 1, 2...

I am getting `BAD_ACCESS_ERROR`. What is the problem here and how can I correct to use it?

Comment: You're adding the Objects from `obj2` and `obj3` to `scnArray` but you ARE not getting (or storing anywhere) the array resulting from the merge of the arrays... Have a look at my answer...

Comment: Your property should also be `strong` or `retain`, not assign.

Comment: Thanks Mike, changing the property as strong works great. Thanks all for your inputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
NSArray  *obj1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"0",@"0",nil];
NSArray  *obj2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"3",@"0",nil];
NSArray  *obj3 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"5",nil];

scnArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:obj1];
scnArray = [scnArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:obj2];
scnArray = [scnArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:obj3];
```

The `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` function adds all objects from array B to array A, and return the result (=the array containing both A's and B's elements).

So, you should simply GET that result... :-)

**IMPORTANT :** `scnArray` MUST be an `NSMutableArray` array, and NOT an `NSArray` (it's changing, right?); so make sure you edit that part too...

**ALSO :** `NSArray *caseArray = [scnArray objectAtIndex:index];` - this doesn't make any sense. Setting an array to an ELEMENT of the `scnArray`? It doesn't contain arrays, right? It just contains ELEMENTS of those arrays (the ones we've added)...

Answer (score 2):

`arrayByAddingObject:` does not add the new object to the receiver, it creates a completely new array and returns it.  You should use something like:

```
scnArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
```

Don't forget that if you are not using ARC or GC, all of these arrays will need to be released at some point.

Comment: I used this earlier. But I access this as  NSArray *caseArray = [scnArray objectAtIndex:1]; I am keep getting EXE_BAD_ACCESS error.